# How to store 1MB data in a cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to store 1000KB (~1MB) of data in a cookie in JavasSript but it is not working.

How can I do this?

Comment: A normal string in JavaScript can be more then a megabyte in length; and variables can represent *any* object. However, data-loss (or exceptions) could occur if trying to use such a long string with `setCookie`. Please include more information about what "isn't work". Newer "HTML5" Browsers exposes various "local storage" and web/indexed databases. (Although 1MB might be too big for that as well?)

Comment: About max size limit for a javascript string, There is a good answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926263/javascript-object-max-size-limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a cookie use localStorage.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage

Most browsers allow 5mb per domain, but IE will give you 10mb per domain.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that. Sending a megabyte of data takes a lot of time (often more than a second). Keep some session status hidden inside your server. Then your cookie string is just a small opaque identifier which should be keyed by the server.

Answer (score 0):

For IE, and I'm sure most other browsers, the limit is around 4K

> For one domain name, each cookie is limited to 4,096 bytes

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306070

Comment: Can i use variable other than cookie

Comment: Are you trying to persist data between page loads or just manage data for the current page?